# unable to open serial port in Eclipse - using Processing and communicating with Arduino Uno

Tags: java, eclipse, arduino, serial-port

I am using Processing in Eclipse to receive data from an Ardiuno Uno and so far I have been unable to open a port in Eclipse.

I have tried the following libraries: processing.serial, jSerialComm, and jssc. With each of them I am able to find the port ('COM6' in this case) but unable to open it. I am able to communicate successfully between the Uno and a Processing sketch, just not between the Uno and Eclipse.

```java
// jSerialComm - just the basic startup code
println((Object[])SerialPort.getCommPorts());
if (SerialProt.getCommPorts().length > 0)
     comPort = SerialPort.getCommPorts()[0]; // this works and prints
                                             // 'COM6' to the console

println("Open port: " + comPort.openPort()); // this does not work,
                                             // prints 'Open port: false' to console
```

With jssc I get the error message "port busy". With jSerialComm I am unable to open the port and with processing.serial the same. The port in the Arduino IDE is set to COM6, as is the port setting in Device Manager. I am using 64-bit Windows 7.

thank you for any help

Comment: Do you have your Arduino IDE console open?

Comment: That sounds like something is already using that COM port. As @MarcosG. suggested it could be the Arduino IDE. COM ports can only be opened by one application.

Comment: Marcos G - no - made sure it was closed

Comment: I tried using a different port ('COM8') but had same results. I also just tried another library, 'jSerial', again with same results.

Comment: The consistency of these results leads me to believe it is one thing that is causing this and possibly something simple....

Comment: How are you deciding which port number to use? The port should exist... Check on your device manager.

Comment: how do you know that you are trying to open com8? you just open the first one which could be a virtual com port for windows or something like that.

Comment: It is set to COM6 in device manager and COM6 in the Arduino IDE. In Device Manager COM3,4,5 and 7 are 'in use'.

Comment: regarding COM8 - I just tried it again: I set the Arduino Uno port in Device Manager to COM8, then did the same in the Arduino IDE, closed the IDE and ran my software in Eclipse. The method that acquires a list of available ports (SerialPort.getCommPorts()[]) returned 'COM8' (and nothing else).